# Is there a wildcard search solution that can allow me to search for a given string but allow 2 characters to be wrong/missing/blank in Snowflake?

Tags: sql, regex, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I'm very new to the concept or Regular Expressions and am looking for a wildcard search solution that allows 2 or fewer characters of the string to be wrong/missing/blank, in Snowflake.
For example, if I have a table's column of basketball players' names such as '**lebron james**', 'carmelo anthony', 'kobe bryant', below are the results I would like to have matched from another table (consumers' search queries) for 'lebron james':

'lebrn james' (missing 'o')

'lebronjames' (missing a space between fn and ln)

'lebrn jme' (missing 'o' and 'a')

'lebron james' (exact match)

Would anyone be so kind to provide some guidance?

Comment: You are asking a lot--too much, I'm afraid--of regular expressions.

Comment: That's not possible with regular expressions. You cannot write `any two characters wrong or missing` as a regex. If your aim is matching strings even if they're spelled slightly wrong, then you might research "phonetic similarity". As far as I know that won't be possible with SQL, you'll have to use a programming language for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDITDISTANCE](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/editdistance.html) is what you are asking for:

```
with input(str) as (
    select * from values
    ('lebrn james'), ('lebronjames'), ('lebrn jme')
), targets(str) as (
    select * from values
    ('lebron james'), ('carmelo anthony'), ('kobe bryant')
)
select i.str, t.str, editdistance(i.str, t.str)
from input i
cross join targets t;
```

gives:

| STR | STR_2 | EDITDISTANCE(I.STR, T.STR) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| lebrn james | lebron james | 1 |
| lebrn james | carmelo anthony | 14 |
| lebrn james | kobe bryant | 10 |
| lebronjames | lebron james | 1 |
| lebronjames | carmelo anthony | 13 |
| lebronjames | kobe bryant | 10 |
| lebrn jme | lebron james | 3 |
| lebrn jme | carmelo anthony | 13 |
| lebrn jme | kobe bryant | 9 |